# Como acrescentar um get sem substituir o que já tem?

Tags: php, html

Não sei se é assim, mas o que eu quero fazer é basicamente manter os parametros do GET que já tem na página, por exemplo tá assim:

http://localhost/forum/topico/verTopicos.php?id=1

E eu to mandando outro GET de um filtro que estou fazendo, e ele está substituindo o atual get ficando assim

http://localhost/forum/topico/verTopicos.php?filtro=respostas

A questão é, teria alguma forma de acrescentar o GET de filtro no de cima depois do ID? Ficando por exemplo assim:

http://localhost/forum/topico/verTopicos.php?id=1&filtro=respostas

Meu código está assim:

```
if (isset($_GET['id']) && !empty($_GET['id'])) {
$idArea = $_GET['id'];
$sqlArea = mysqli_query($conexao, "SELECT nomeArea FROM area WHERE idArea = '$idArea'");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sqlArea)) {
    $nomeArea = utf8_encode($row['nomeArea']);
}

$ordernar = "posts.dataPost DESC";

// FILTRO
if(isset($_GET['filtro'])){
    $filtro = $_GET['filtro'];
    switch($filtro){
        case ('views'):
            $ordernar = "visualizacoes DESC";
            break;
        case ('autor'):
            $ordernar = "Autor DESC";
            break;
        case ('titulo'):
            $ordernar = "topico.titulo ASC";
            break;
    }
}

<form method="GET" class="form-inline">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="listarPor">Listar por:</label>
          <select name="filtro" class="form-control" onchange="this.form.submit()">
              <option>Selecione</option>
              <option value="views">Visualizações</option>
              <option value="autor">Usuário</option>
              <option value="respostas">Respostas</option>
              <option value="titulo">Título</option>
          </select>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Logo após o `form`, adicione um campo hidden

```
<form method="GET" class="form-inline">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $idArea;?>">
```

O restante continua como está.

Comment: Obrigado Daniel, essa foi a solução mais simples porem funcional.